# Small exercise in topology

Tags: general-topology

I have a small question i have a topological space $(\mathbb{N},\tau)$ where $\tau=\{\emptyset,,\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N}^*, \{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N^*}}\}$, $A_n=\{1,2,....,n\}$ and we consider the set $A=\{2n, n\in \mathbb{N}^*\}$

I want to find $\overline{A}$ and $\overset{º}{A}$ and $A'$

I found $\overline{A}=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}, A'=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1,2\}, \overset{º}{A}=\emptyset, Fr(A)= \overline{A}$ is it true ?

Thank you

Comment: What is $\mathbb{N}^{*}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^*=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: @user46944: what should it be else ?

Comment: @idm Are you suggesting it's common knowledge that $\mathbb{N}^{*} = \mathbb{N} - \{ 0 \}$?  It wasn't common enough for me to know it.  And in what useful way does your comment add to this discussion?

Comment: @idm Even if you suspect to know that it is always good to make sure. There is no need for the OP to leave that unmentioned.

Comment: @drhab Thinking as you think is the direct road to justifying one day people asking "what's + ?" in $(\mathbf{N},+)$. There are basic notations that everyone should be aware of, and if note, google could be their friend, as one says.

Comment: Please I need an answer to my question can you told me if it is right what i found ?

Comment: @RobertGreen I think that is completely silly. When someone uses an uncommon notation that you think you *might* understand but are not $100\%$ sure, you should ask. No one is going to ask about what $+$ means with regards to $\Bbb N$...

Comment: @RobertGreen In your example, how can anyone be sure what $+$ means without specification?  Technically, $+$ is just a symbol that could stand for any operation you want.  Is it really such a bother to clarify what you mean for the audience?  I'm not at all friends with ambiguity when it comes to math.

Comment: @RobertGreen "everyone should be aware of". Well I am the living proof of it that that is not the case. This in spite of the fact that I doing topology for quite some years. Also there are (or can be) international differences. Comparing it with $+$ is not correct here.

Comment: @drhab What I am saying is that the more you (it is a generic "you", not you) keep asking people to define what trivial a well-known notations mean, the more people will tend to ask for the meaning of even more trivial things. Saying it's ok to ask what $\mathbf{N}^{*}$ is of course ok, but the real answer should be : "go first have a look in a book, or, if you don't have books, on internet as you oviously have internet, and you'll find out." The more you lower your standard, the more you'll have to deal with silly questions.

Comment: @user46944 You are perfectly right ! That why I always have picture of the sun on me, so that when I speak about the sun, I can show pictures to people so they can see what I mean by "sun", in case they mean something else by "sun", as "sun" is simply a word symbol for something that could be different depending on people. Good luck.

Comment: @RobertGreen Rude.

Comment: @user46944 But true.

Comment: @RobertGreen Not at all.  But you've lost your credibility with me since you felt the need to be rude.

Comment: @CameronWilliams This we will see... As I said, the more you lower your standard, the more you'll have to deal with silly questions.

Comment: @user46944 I am just giving you an example formally equivalent to what we are "debating here", example where you wouldn't have the same opinion as the one you have on the what does $\mathbf{N}^{*}$ mean ?" case. Why is it rude ? Because you're not agreeing with yourself ? ;-)

Comment: @RobertGreen The fear ("the more...the more...") you describe is not shared by me. I have never notified that tendency in this context. Secondly you can also interpret questions on "trivial" yet shadowy things as a stimulus for OP's to formulate their questions on a way clear for as much as possible. That is in my view a good cause.

Comment: @RobertGreen Wow, you really want to make a point here.  This issue is trivial at best compared to the problems in the world.  I'm going to go worry about better things.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all of your answers are correct. If $n\in\Bbb N^*$, every open nbhd of $2n$ also contains $2n-1$, so $\operatorname{int}A=\varnothing$, which ensures that the frontier of $A$ is $\operatorname{cl}A$. $1$ is an isolated point, so it’s not in the closure of $A$, but if $2n+1$ is an odd number greater than $1$, then every nbhd of $2n+1$ also contains $2n\in A$, and the only nbhd of $0$ is $\Bbb N$, so $\operatorname{cl}A=\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$. The arguments that I’ve already given show that $1$ is not a limit point of $A$, that the larger odd numbers are limit points of $A$, and that $0$ is a limit point of $A$. $A_2$ is a nbhd of $2$ that contains no other point of $A$, so $2$ is not a limit point of $A$, but if $n$ is any larger even number, every nbhd of $n$ contains $n-2$, which is in $A$, so $n$ is a limit point of $A$. Thus, $A'=\Bbb N\setminus\{1,2\}$, as you said.